# How to disable all the buttons in the layout for a certain amount of time, java.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

**secondScreen.java**

public class secondScreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
//drawables
int res[] = new int[] {R.drawable.brownbars,R.drawable.centeredorangedot, R.drawable.dots, R.drawable.greenlines, R.drawable.lightbulb, R.drawable.orangedots, R.drawable.orangelines, R.drawable.tree, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.yellowwithred, R.drawable.brownbars,R.drawable.centeredorangedot,
        R.drawable.dots, R.drawable.greenlines, R.drawable.lightbulb, R.drawable.orangedots, R.drawable.orangelines, R.drawable.tree, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.yellowwithred};
int lay1, lay2, shuffleCount = 0, gameCount = 0;
ImageButton first, second;
LinearLayout layout;


ImageButton b1;
ImageButton b2;
ImageButton b3;
ImageButton b4;
ImageButton b5;
ImageButton b6;
ImageButton b7;
ImageButton b8;
ImageButton b9;
ImageButton b10;
ImageButton b11;
ImageButton b12;
ImageButton b13;
ImageButton b14;
ImageButton b15;
ImageButton b16;
ImageButton b17;
ImageButton b18;
ImageButton b19;
ImageButton b20;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    Intent activityThatCalled = getIntent();


    //initialize all buttons in game
    b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b4);
    b5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b5);
    b6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b6);
    b7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b7);
    b8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b8);
    b9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b9);
    b10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b10);
    b11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b11);
    b12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b12);
    b13 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b13);
    b14 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b14);
    b15 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b15);
    b16 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b16);
    b17 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b17);
    b18 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b18);
    b19 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b19);
    b20 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b20);

    iconRandomizer();



};

public void randomCheck(ImageButton btn, int image) {

    if (gameCount < 2) {
        gameCount++;
        if (gameCount == 1) {
            first = btn;
            lay1 = image;
        } else {
            second = btn;
            lay2 = image;


            if (lay1 != lay2) {
                ArrayList<View> touchables = layout.getTouchables();
                for(View touchable : touchables) {
                    if (touchable instanceof Button)
                        ((Button) touchable).setEnabled(false);
                }
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        first.setImageResource(R.color.material_blue_grey_800);
                        second.setImageResource(R.color.material_blue_grey_800);
                        first.setEnabled(true);
                        second.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                }, 1000);

            }
            gameCount = 0;

        }


    }
}

static void shuffleArray(int[] ar)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        // Simple swap
        int a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }
}




public void iconRandomizer() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.println(res[i]);


    shuffleArray(res);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.println(res[i]);

    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    b4.setOnClickListener(this);
    b5.setOnClickListener(this);
    b6.setOnClickListener(this);
    b7.setOnClickListener(this);
    b8.setOnClickListener(this);
    b9.setOnClickListener(this);
    b10.setOnClickListener(this);
    b11.setOnClickListener(this);
    b12.setOnClickListener(this);
    b13.setOnClickListener(this);
    b14.setOnClickListener(this);
    b15.setOnClickListener(this);
    b16.setOnClickListener(this);
    b17.setOnClickListener(this);
    b18.setOnClickListener(this);
    b19.setOnClickListener(this);
    b20.setOnClickListener(this);

}




public void onClick(View v){


    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.b1:
            b1.setImageResource(res[0]);
            b1.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b1, res[0]);

            break;
        case R.id.b2:
            b2.setImageResource(res[1]);
            b2.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b2,res[1]);

            break;
        case R.id.b3:
            b3.setImageResource(res[2]);
            b3.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b3, res[2]);

            break;
        case R.id.b4:
            b4.setImageResource(res[3]);
            b4.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b4, res[3]);

            break;
        case R.id.b5:
            b5.setImageResource(res[4]);
            b5.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b5, res[4]);

            break;
        case R.id.b6:
            b6.setImageResource(res[5]);
            b6.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b6, res[5]);

            break;
        case R.id.b7:
            b7.setImageResource(res[6]);
            b7.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b7, res[6]);

            break;
        case R.id.b8:
            b8.setImageResource(res[7]);
            b8.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b8, res[7]);

            break;
        case R.id.b9:
            b9.setImageResource(res[8]);
            b9.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b9, res[8]);

            break;
        case R.id.b10:
            b10.setImageResource(res[9]);
            b10.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b10, res[9]);

            break;
        case R.id.b11:
            b11.setImageResource(res[10]);
            b11.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b11, res[10]);

            break;
        case R.id.b12:
            b12.setImageResource(res[11]);
            b12.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b12, res[11]);

        case R.id.b13:
            b13.setImageResource(res[12]);
            b13.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b13, res[12]);

            break;
        case R.id.b14:
            b14.setImageResource(res[13]);
            b14.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b14, res[13]);

        case R.id.b15:
            b15.setImageResource(res[14]);
            b15.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b15, res[14]);

            break;
        case R.id.b16:
            b16.setImageResource(res[15]);
            b16.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b16, res[15]);

            break;
        case R.id.b17:
            b17.setImageResource(res[16]);
            b17.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b17, res[16]);

            break;
        case R.id.b18:
            b18.setImageResource(res[17]);
            b18.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b18, res[17]);

            break;
        case R.id.b19:
            b19.setImageResource(res[18]);
            b19.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b19, res[18]);

            break;
        case R.id.b20:
            b20.setImageResource(res[19]);
            b20.setEnabled(false);
            randomCheck(b20, res[19]);


            break;
    }


}
```

//}

```
}
```

**error log:**

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.widget.LinearLayout.getTouchables()' on a null object reference
        at eagle.abhishekravi.abhishek.eagle.secondScreen.randomCheck(secondScreen.java:111)
        at eagle.abhishekravi.abhishek.eagle.secondScreen.onClick(secondScreen.java:232)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I am making a memory match game, and I need to disable all **buttons** after the second `Button` is tapped. Then after the check is complete, it will resume normally. I have got the checks to work but still need the buttons disabled in this case where user taps another `Button` between the 1 second pause.Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!!

Comment: if you initialized a `RelativeLayout` there is something wrong in your code.... look at your error stacktrace: `LinearLayout.getTouchables()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided by the error message, it looks like `layout` is null. If you're still having trouble, the code where `layout` is being set would be very helpful.

Your layout should be accessed via `R.layout.my_layout`.

Comment: I have a layout.xml file for this activity and I initialized it RelativeLayout layout, is that a problem?

Comment: How else would I disable all the buttons in a specific layout?

Comment: We'll need some more context. Could you please provide the code where `layout` is being set?

Comment: layout is simply just a layout.xml file, I'm new to android, sorry if I do something stupid.

Comment: No worries. It looks like `layout` is never being set. It's being declared, but never initialized. You're likely looking to do something like `layout = R.layout.layout`, but you could just use `R.layout.layout` instead - like you do in `onCreate( Bundle )`

Comment: To help clarify, if you were to create a new XML layout named `my_layout.xml`, then you would be able to access it via `R.layout.my_layout`. This class is dynamically updated by the Android SDK.

Comment: R.layout.layout.getTouchables(); doesn't work, do you know why? R.layout.layout returns an int, but I don't know how to incorporate the function into it.